# Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition x64 on a Windows Server 2008 VM. I run the installer for a standalone installation and this works fine for the setup support rules bit. That passes ok but then I get this error:

### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created..

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

How can I resolve this? I am getting 2008 R2 CTP but this is just a CTP. My download is from DreamSpark.

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

This isn't really a real solution, but it worked for me after the 5th attempt. Not sure if it makes a difference, but on the 5th attempt I minimized all other windows (so that SQL setup is the only window that has focus) since the issue appears to be UI related.

*Update:* After overcoming the 1st issue, I got another issue where the actual database engine component failed to install without reason. The solution was to restart and try again.

The x64 installer seems to be really buggy.

Comment: Minimizing all the windows solved my problem with the 32 bit installer.

Comment: Definitely not the best solution, but it worked. I think I had a lot more that 5 attempts but got it going eventually.

Comment: Its very strange but closing all windows and running setup from run command works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

I've did another trick:

1. In the Installation Disc you will find a folder, x86 and x64
2. Select as per your OS and go inside the folder
3. Click on the LandingPage.exe
4. It will show the page, in that click on the second Option on the left hand menu "Installation"
5. Click on "Start Standalone installation from the menu at the right side
6. It will ask for the location files on the disc
7. Show the location, 
   e.g. `<Your Disc Drive>/SQL Server Enterprise 2008/x86`

It will complete the installation successfully

Comment: You a champ my friend

Answer (score 2):

I see MS has answered this. It's because the release of MSSSQL is newer than the SP is. They have a hotfix that apparently needs application. Oh joy!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975055

You then have to request the Hotfix, and wait for the link to be sent to you. They say 5 minutes, but we'll see.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 64 Bit, press ctrl+alt+delete, start the task manager and end the landing page process and it will successfully install.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error a number of times trying to install SQL Express 2008 x64 on a 2008 R2 64-bit server (VMWare) and I finally got it working doing the following:

Start the installation and when it gets to the point where the security window pops up asking you if you authorize the installation to run, open the temp folder.  C:{GUID} and copy that folder (contains setup.exe and supporting files) to your desktop.

Click "OK" on the security dialog and it will probably error.

Once the error dialog goes away just run the setup.exe from the temporary directory on your desktop and it works.

Hope this helps someone else.

~Matt Heidenreich

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when i was installing on Window 7.  The only thing I could find was to retry the install again right after the failure and it worked after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem; made sure no other instance of setup was running from process explorer and then restarted installation and it worked fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Before Installation, close all  *windows explorer* and  *web browser*. :)

.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once with installing the service pack.  The only thing I could find was to retry the install again right after the failure.  It took about five times, but it eventually worked.  I think there's something odd about the installer on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

closing all open windows worked for me. definitely a UI problem with 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

For Server 2003 with this issue, I installed 2008 R2 management tools - which should work fine with 2008.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985

Note: Needs PowerShell on 2003 to install: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20020